# How to stop postman replacing string with dynamic var

Tags: postman

I'm trying to send this raw JSON-body:

`{ "guid": "{{$guid}}" }`

But postman is replacing the string {{$guid}} with a dynamic guid, which I understand, but I just need to send the exact string "{{$guid}}" without postman replacing it with a randomly generated guid.

Is there any way to prevent postman from replacing the string?

Comment: I think this is not supported. All sorts of different escaping doesn't work, setting it from env variables and pre-scripts doesn't work either, there's nothing on this in the docs. It might be less painful to just use a different client for such a case.

Comment: Seems to be working now